# Why did all Kurta Clan get beaten up even though they have the Scarlet Eyes?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Kurapika is so powerful with his Scarlet Eye. We already know that all Kurta Clan has the Scarlet Eye.

According to that, why did all the other members of the Kurta Clan get massacred by the Phantom Troupe?

Couldn't they use the Scarlet Eye to fight back Phantom Troupe? Is there no "hero" in Kurta clan, or in this context, a person that has improved and mastered his Scarlet Eye?

Comment: I guess, people of kurta clan may not know the to use the Nen, and fighting against Nen takes gives disadvantage to non nen user.. Also I guess Kurapika is only one who got out from his village to outside world, though I am not sure of it for other people

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an inherent assumption in the question, "IF Kurapika is so powerful with his scarlet eyes...". Yes it is true that when a member of Kurta clan becomes enraged they gain an increase in physical strength, however they lose their rationality and revert to a primal form. We do not know if the "Scarlet Eyes" causing Kurpika to become a specialist is unique to him or the Kurta clan. Your other question regarding the so called "hero" has simply no base or answer at all because the Manga gives no information.

However, you've to understand that the Phantom Troupe themselves are very powerful Nen Users. They can easily go against numerous "physically powerful" people, they can easily kill them. This is what Nen brings to the table and all members of The Phantom Troupe.

Kurapika was able to bridge the gap by utilizing his "Scarlet Eyes". He was able to turn his eyes Scarlet at will. By utilizing the conditions of Limitations and putting his own life at stake he greatly boosted his Nen abilities. He is a skilled Nen User, has high combat prowess, genius level intellect, and enhanced speed, perception and reflexes.

To end, as far as we know Kurapika is strong BECAUSE of his clan massacre and his innate skill and not because of his clan. The Phantom Troupe is an elite group of Nen Users who can take on any other high level fighters. We don't have enough history about Kurta clan to know if there was another "hero" for the clan.

Comment: @Gagantous My answer already covers that bit. We don't have enough info on Kurta or their eyes. So we don't know if there was resistance, were they ambushed.... Buffs due to the eyes can be easily negated by a skilled fighter. HxH focuses on fights where anyone can beat anyone.

Answer (score 1):

The Kuruta are not a warrior born people. They are reclusive and peaceful and prefer to be left alone. This is the only reason why they were massacred.

There are no backstories to support why they chose to be so, however, their scarlet eyes does lean towards them being highly aggressive in the past. And must've been the foremost reason why they chose to live outside of other's reach.

They are inherently strong creatures due to their nature but as I've said they are peaceful beings.

It's easy to assume they do not use nen, because if they did they would have been extremely powerful as Kurapica is.

And for Uvogin to say that it was a hard job taking their eyes and have stated that they were really strong. One could only assume that like Kurapica, most of them has the ability of Emperor Time as well, giving them nen and boosting their power levels at a considerable level. Because Specialist ability is hereditary(blood line), the Kuruta having the Emperor Time is a very likely probability.

Comment: This seems like a lot of speculation and is very unsupported.  They show an unusual characteristic when emotional so must be genetically disposed to aggressiveness.  Torturing a whole race of people to death was hard so they must all have magic and one particularly rare type of magic at that. I would argue that nen affinity is clearly genetic based on Killua's and Gon's families but you don't make that point.

Comment: They are predisposed to being aggressive, as evidenced by Kurapica's sudden outburst on the thugs that were bullying them. One reason is that they are mostly feared creatures, which would elicit violent responses and therefore stroke their emotional responses into one direction and that is to be aggressive. Also Uvogin is an immensely powerful combatant and for him to say that it wasn't an easy job can only mean the Kuruta's Scarlet Eyes are immensely powerful. "Specialists have abilities that are either genetic or will develop in time depending on circumstance and environment".

Comment: We can't assume historical behavior of whole clan by evaluating one special member even if the member is the only one left. He didn't just kill the clan.  He tortured them to death one by one to cause the most possible emotional pain and the best color.  He easily could just be saying that it was a lot of work. More importantly though: What is the source for your quote?  If reputable and canon, that is the best argument yet that "emperor time" is tied to the Kurta clan and not just to Kurapica.

Comment: I edited my answer. Uvogin specifically said they were really strong. That's the pillar to the rationality of my assumptions. From what we've heard or read, they were always depicted as reclusive and peaceful, while to some are demonic. Which prompts me to say they might have a history of violence, since their Scarlet Eyes forces them to go into a berserk like state(from what we've seen in Kurapica). And therefore ultimately becoming reclusive for that sole reason alone. So yes, in accordance to the question, I try to back my answer with details(facts) that would tie in to it very well.